# Not able to create any portlet on Liferay 6.2 CE GA4 Offline without internet

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay

I have created a fresh Liferay 6.2 CE GA4 using pre-downloaded SDK/Tomcat/LR Source. I have created server in eclipse and when I try to create portlet for the first time it try to download "`gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip`" from the internet.

I have downloaded same from gradle from "https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip" and placed it inside "liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\tools\gradle\gradle\wrapper".

Still it shows the same error as below:

```
`Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:56)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:42)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:57)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
`
```

Am I placing that zip on wrong directory or missing something else ?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, I'd say: Yes, it seems you put the file into the wrong directory. Which one is the correct one? I don't know. It'd be easiest to do your first build while connected to the internet. The download will just happen once (also, there might be more dependencies that need to be downloaded) and you can do your builds offline after that.

Comment: Due to some restriction I am not able to go online. That is the issue. Thanks for response.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I am connected to internet and organization proxy settings are also configured in eclipse. I am able to install other software but liferay portlet creation is not working due to same error. Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem, you need to:

> 1) Delete content on:
>   D:\Profiles\XXX.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-bin\88n1whbyjvxg3s40jzz5ur27
>
> 2) Download manually:
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip
>
> 3) Put gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip on:
>   D:\Profiles\XXX.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-bin\88n1whbyjvxg3s40jzz5ur27